# Eclipse Java EE: When starting Application, stop old running instance

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I am searching for a way in Eclipse to stop all running instances of a Java Application when clicking run, to assure only one instance of the program is running at the same time.

I am programming a server application and it's obvious that you can only run that once, just thing of the socket bindings etc.

Of course you can stop it manually each time, but as I also have client applications running I have to change the console each time and click the red stop icon. This is retarding the development process.